# How do I Set Minimum and Maximum Zoom Level in Nokia HERE Maps API?

Tags: here-api

I was able to set minimum and maximum zoom level for clustered data points in Nokia HERE Maps API 3.0. But, I can't seem to figure out the way to do this for regular markers.

**How can I set a minimum and maximum zoom level for markers?**

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Which **HERE SDK** are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a mix-max zoom config for a nomal Marker, but it can be easily achieved using Map listener, a simple example is as follows

```
var minZoom=5;
var maxZoom=13;
marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat:50.16 , lng: 8.63});
map.addObject(marker);

map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function () {
    var zoom=map.getZoom(); 
    if(zoom>=minZoom && zoom<=maxZoom)  {
        marker.setVisibility(true);
    }else{
        marker.setVisibility(false);
    }   
});
```